# Correct way to set the content language of a POST request

Tags: javascript, post

What is the proper way to indicate the language of the content of a POST request made by the client? I looked into `Accept-Language` and `Content-Language`. The first seems to be hinting the server that I want a document in a certain language. The second one is a header set by the server.

I would like to indicate the language of the POST payload as a header. Is `Content-Language` acceptable or is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [spec for `Content-Language`](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.12) does not restrict it to being a response header.

It applies equally to requests and responses.